# how to decrease a number in machine language

Tags: python, pseudocode

I want to add `-1` and a number which is placed at memory address `0x36`.

First, I loaded memory address bit pattern which is in `0x36` in a register and I loaded memory address `ff` (two's complement notation=-1) and add them. But my tutor said this solution is not true.

So, how can I decrease a number by `-1` with only addition and bring them registers?

Comment: Could you show your actual code (or pseudo code) please?

Comment: It is machine language and consist of operands as well as opcode like 1536(load the register 5 with a  value from 36. memory cell)

Comment: The answer depends on how many bits your registries hold. If `8`, then adding `0xff` will subtract `1`. If `16` then add `0xffff`, etc.